# Local Internal Database in Flash & SQLite

Tags: flash, sqlite

I need to store a large amount of data that will be internally accessed often within a flash file. The database is temporary and does not need to be stored in an external file.

Is it possible to use SQLite to create a database that may be used internally in flash? As far as access speeds are concerned, is this an efficient solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. SQLite can't be used with flash. It can be used with Adobe AIR projects only. You can consider using XML or JSON. Or just use objects.